# How to use nginx proxy_pass when using a location other than /?

Tags: nginx, devops, reverse-proxy, proxypass

So here is the configuration I am working with.

```
location /dashboard/{
        proxy_pass http//localhost:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
 
}
```

localhost/dashboard/ loads up my webapp which is equivalent to localhost:5000/

When I click on the Home link for example. I want it to go to localhost/dashboard/Home but instead it redirects to localhost/Home.
This doesn't match the /dashboard/ location block and instead is caught by the location / block.
Nginx starts searching in its root folder for the Home file which of course isn't present.

Everything works fine if I manually type in localhost/dashboard/Home in the browser.

```
location /Home/Module/{
       proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/Home/Module;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;

}
```

This block works fine as well. But I don't want to be doing this.

Defining dashboard in the backend might work as well but I want to know if I can somehow configure it without modifying the backend.

Comment: What kind of webapp are you using? It's not nginx fault, you need to adjust your webapp with the basePath its running on, so it knows to generate the links with the correct subdirectory.